# Unable to get Node.js hello world application working [Fedora 21]

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, fedora, fedora-21

I'm trying to write a node.js application, trying to make sure my environment set up first.

The webserver is Fedora 21, and I have opened port 3000 on the firewall and flushed ip tables. nmap localhost indicates that port 3000 is listening.

I'm using this node application

```
var http = require('http');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log('%d request received', process.pid);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello world!\n');
}).listen(PORT);

console.log('%d listening on %d', process.pid, PORT);
```

But when I navigate the browser to my server I don't get any hello world message like intended.

Comment: Nothing, asside from the initial listening message I do not get anything.

Comment: You're navigating to `localhost:3000` right? Your code works fine for me.

Comment: another note, using lynx and nagivating to it on the localhost also yield no result

Comment: I just used firefox, no problems at all.

Comment: oh, looks like I'm an idiot, doing host:3000 works.

Comment: Fedora 21 is EOL. You should not use outdated systems and update to current Fedora 23.

Comment: @Jakuje I am not the admin, I have no control over which server we use. they literally just threw a VM at me and said have fun

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check for firewall rules? IIRC many firewalls prefer to drop packets instead of actively rejecting -- so you may find that (eventually) the web browser times out.
Easy way to check:
In one console, do: nc -l -p {whatever your PORT environment variable is set to, or 3000, as per your server logic}
and in another console, do
echo hello | nc localhost 9999

If you see the hello in the first console, you can at least rule out some tcp oddness / firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion I'm an idiot who needs another cup of coffee.

it works 100% just instead of navigating to hostname/webapp I need to navigate to hostname:3000